# Website internatinalization issues

Tags: php, internationalization, multilingual

Nearly in every multilanguage project I was changing translation logic. For blog like projects I was creating new columns in database like `title_en, title_ru ... and content_en, content_ru...` So basically if we have id of blogpost, we have access to all languages. It works well but I know that column based translation is not flexible and not good direction. So I was thinking about row based translation where every blogpost's row will have columns like: `id, title, content, locale`.

But this way also has problems and one of them for me is, how to build connection between blogpost and it's translations?

I mean if you opened blogpost in english for example and you change your language to russian, how to know which blogpost to open?

One way to use 1 token for all tranlations of page. is it good to use 1 token for all translations of page? I mean

```
example.com/en/mypage
example.com/ru/mypage
example.com/de/mypage
```

Please share your experience with me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal does this really well. You have a column in called tid (translation id). You set a master language then point the tid to the master language column.

So your table would be like this(ish)

---

### | id | lang | title | body | tid |

### | 1  | en   | hello | hello world | 0 | // master node has no tid

### | 2  | fr   | bonjour | bonjour (french word for world) | 1 |

### | 3  | sp   | hola    | hola (spanish stuff) | 1 |

Then you can use the tid and lang to find everything but still have per row entries.

example.com/en/mypage 
select * from pages where id=1

exmaple.com/fr/mypage
select * from pages where tid=1 and lang="fr"